# Profiling: Why wouldn't you just use %%time over python -m timeit?

Tags: python, profiling

Why is it preferred to use `!python -m timeit` as opposed to `%%time`?

Instead of using `!python -m timeit` in bash, wouldnt it be much easier to just include `%%time` in potentially slow code blocks?

I've included a screen shot of both methods as well as the code:
[image]

```
%%time
longstr = ""
for x in range(1000):
  longstr += str(x)

%%time
longstr = "".join([str(x) for x in range(1000)])

!python -m timeit 'longstr=""' 'for x in range(1000): longstr += str(x)'
!python -m timeit '"".join([str(x) for x in range(1000)])'
```

Comment: Your question would be much better if rephrased, "what's the difference between..."/"When would I choose A over B, or B over A"?

Comment: `%timeit` and `%%timeit` are only usable inside ipython (and derivatives), whereas `python -m timeit` is usable, well, everywhere. If you're inside ipython I'd say it's preferable to use the magic since it has better formatting.

Comment: Is your question "Why would you choose to run your code with a timing flag in the console where you're already running it rather than editing your code or using a magic command in a different, interactive console?"

Answer (score 0):

The `%` commands are [ipython magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit), which are only available within an ipython environment.

`python -m timeit` is executing `timeit` (a python module) as an independent standalone tool, e.g. from a bash shell. (The `!` prefix means telling ipython to "run this code from the shell".)

Making some assumptions about your use-cases, I suggest using `%timeit` for personal convenience and using `!python -m timeit` when producing & sharing results with others (for reproducibility, since it's more standalone & independent).